# Gitkraken disconnected branches

Tags: git, gitlab, gitkraken

I have two 'disconnected' branches in GitKraken, which I cannot merge together. When I am checked out in one branch, I cannot right-click on the other one. Pushing/pulling to/from the server does not resolve anything. Is there any way to fix this?

I am not sure what my steps were to get to the problems, but it was roughly like 
this:

- Create git-repo locally
- make some edits, initialize Git Flow, et cetera.
- Made the decision to add an remote location, on Gitlab
- Created a new repo there
- First commit on `master` (included a `README.md` because I was unsure how to push from GitKraken to an empty repo)
- Pulled `master` from GitKraken
- Pushed `develop` to Gitlab

[image: disconnected branches]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by going to Gitlab, and make a pull request from `develop` to `master` there (and accept it). Fetching and pulling in GitKraken makes sure they are connected (as seen in the below picture).

[image: Connected!]